# How do I make a while loop assign a variable?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, variables

```
def valid():
    while True:
        hiOrLo = input("Type 'h' for higher and 'l' for lower.")
        if hiOrLo == "h" or hiOrLo == "l":
            return 
        else:
            print("Invalid, try again")

hiOrLo = 0
valid()

print(hiOrLo)
```

What I understand is that Python won't change a variable through "input" while in the while loop, so when printed hiOrLo will still be "0", but i need hiOrLo to be either "h" or "l", whichever one I select, how do I do this while keeping it a function?

Comment: hiOrLo will equal whatever the input is, to use that outside the function you can simply `return hiOrLo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have the function return that value, then save a reference to it.

```
def valid():
    while True:
        hiOrLo = input("Type 'h' for higher and 'l' for lower.")
        if hiOrLo == "h" or hiOrLo == "l":
            return hiOrLo
        else:
            print("Invalid, try again")

hiOrLo = valid()

print(hiOrLo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the global keyword:

```
def valid():
    global hiOrLo
    while True:
        hiOrLo = input("Type 'h' for higher and 'l' for lower.")
        if hiOrLo == "h" or hiOrLo == "l":
            return 
        else:
            print("Invalid, try again")

hiOrLo = 0
valid()

print(hiOrLo)
```

Comment: No, you do not in fact need the `global` keyword.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I beg to differ. You can say that you shouldn't use the `global` keyword, but you do need the `global` keyword. I agree that your solution is a better one.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: It means that the solution I provided works, even though it is less desirable.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah You don't *need* the global keyword. It *can* be used to solve this, but using return value is way superior.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think he means to say its a choice of preference. Even so, `global` is the wrong choice here.

Comment: I've never seen `global` be the right choice. Ever.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You should try making your own OS ;) ...wait, with python?

Comment: @neil - In a simple script like this, where the OP is a blank slate for learning good practices, `global` is one of the worst things to be demonstrating. Returning and saving values is fundamental.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That last comment is very true, I want to learn the correct and most efficient ways to code.